# WCF : Multi-dimensional arrays are not supported

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

Different objects with multi-dimensional arrays need to go through a WCF netTcpBinding connection. WCF throws "Multi-dimensional arrays are not supported" when trying.

I can't change the interface of this class. I'm going to create a wrapper that will binary serialize the objects before going through wcf (even if netTcpBinding is supposed to be a binary transfer). Am I right?

I'm looking for an elegant generic design to do that transfer. Any advices from the community before I start that dev (in C# dot net 4)?

Comment: Binary serialize it to a byte stream (single dimension byte array), and deserialize at the other end.

Comment: I expected it would be possible to force WCF to be full binary (not a binary+soap). I didn't find how to do that. Somebody knows something about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change the interface of your WCF service to accept the byte[] instead of the class in question?  Your classes can still have the multi-dimensional arrays, but instead of passing an instance, serialize it to a byte[] and pass that as the parameter.  I think that's what @John Willemse is saying.

EDIT:  It does sound like you can accept changing the WCF service interface since it appears you don't have it 100% fleshed out.  Without your original code I am somewhat limited but something like this example should help guide you:

Change from:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IShipmentManagement
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Process(Shipment shipment);
}
```

to:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IShipmentManagement
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Process(byte[] serializedShipment);
}
```

And then in your code that calls the WCF service you need to binary serialize the "Shipment" instance like so:

```
var shipmentManagement = // however you get a reference to your WCF service
var shipment = new Shipment();

// populate your array or whatever

IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var ms = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(stream, shipment);
var serializedShipment = ms.ToArray();
shipmentManagement.Process(serializedShipment);
```

On the other side you just need to deserialize the byte[] and pass the instance on to whatever code you have.  Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: yes I want to binary transfer it if it's not possible to force wcf in full binary innerly. I'm looking for elegant designs for this wcf interface if you have any ideas.

Comment: What does your current design look like?

Comment: I'm looking for any advices from the community before I start that dev.